# Rcpp Function Compilation Error

Tags: r, rcpp

Original R function:

```
psiBiSquare<-function(r,c){
true<-abs(r)<=c
false<-abs(r)>c
psi<-true*(r*(1-(r/c)^2)^2)+false*0
return(psi)
}
```

I am replacing this with a faster Rcpp implementation below:

```
 #include <Rcpp.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector psiBS_rcpp(NumericVector r, double c) {
int n =r.size();
NumericVector y = clone(r);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
 if(abs(r[i])<=c){
  y[i]=(r*pow(1-pow(r/c,2),2));
 }
 else{
  y[i]=0;
 }
}
 return y;
}
```

The error message is "cannot convert rcpp::sugar::"  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. You have really poor code formatting.  There is no extra fee on spaces. Use them.
2. You are undecided about `r` and use it at the same time as a vector, and its elements as a scalar.  Your right hand side expression is vectorized, yet you try to assign to a scalar `y[i]`.

Improved / corrected source file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]    
NumericVector psiBS_rcpp(NumericVector r, double c) {
  int n = r.size();
  NumericVector y = clone(r);

  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if (abs(r[i]) <=c ) {
      y[i] = (r[i]*pow(1-pow(r[i]/c,2),2));
    }
    else{
      y[i]=0;
    }
  }
  return y;
}

/*** R
psiBiSquare <- function(r,c) {
  true <- abs(r) <= c
  false <- abs(r) > c 
  psi <- true * (r*(1-(r/c)^2)^2) + false*0
  return(psi)
}

r <- seq(-3,3)
c <- 1.5
psiBiSquare(r, c) 
psiBS_rcpp(r, c)
*/
```

Running it:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/ij.cpp")

R> psiBiSquare <- function(r,c) {
+   true <- abs(r) <= c
+   false <- abs(r) > c
+   psi <- true * (r*(1-(r/c)^2)^2) + false*0
+   return(psi)
+ }

R> r <- seq(-3,3)

R> c <- 1.5

R> psiBiSquare(r, c)
[1]  0.000000  0.000000 -0.308642  0.000000  0.308642  0.000000  0.000000

R> psiBS_rcpp(r, c)
[1]  0.000000  0.000000 -0.308642  0.000000  0.308642  0.000000  0.000000
R>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk.  Good advice as always.